# unittest - How to test internal parameter in a function?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm having some issue while creating unittest for internal parameter.

My structure is:

[1] my_animal.py contains Myclass and method: do_bite()

**my_animal.py**

```
class Myclass():
    def do_bite(self):
        return 1
```

[2] my_module.py contains jobMain("") which is using the method from my_animal.py

**my_module.py**

```
import sys
from someclass import Myclass

def jobMain(directoryPath):
    flag = -1
    result = Myclass()

    if result.do_bite() is None:
        flag = 0
    if result.do_bite() is 1:
        flag = 1
    if result.do_bite() is 2:
        flag = 2
```

[3] my_test.py contains the unittest to test jobMain in my_module.py

**my_test.py**

```
# Mock Myclass.dobite to None
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dobite0():
    with mock.patch('my_module.Myclass') as mocked_animal:
        mocked_animal.return_value.do_bite.return_value = None
        yield

# Mock Myclass.dobite to 1
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dobite1():
    with mock.patch('my_module.Myclass') as mocked_animal:
        mocked_animal.return_value.do_bite.return_value = 1
        yield

# Mock Myclass.dobite to 2
@pytest.fixture
def mock_dobite2():
    with mock.patch('my_module.Myclass') as mocked_animal:
        mocked_animal.return_value.do_bite.return_value = 2
        yield

# My unittest to test dobite() method
def test_dobite0(mock_Myclass, mock_dobite0):
   jobMain("")

def test_dobite1(mock_Myclass, mock_dobite1):
   jobMain("")

def test_dobite2(mock_Myclass, mock_dobite2):
   jobMain("")
```

My question is: How to test 'flag' parameter inside JobMain?
'flag' para must be assigned the correct value.( eg: dobite = 1 => flag = 1)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `para` only exists in the scope of `jobMain`. If you want to use the variable outside `jobMain` the most common ways are

### 1) return the value

This is quite obvious. Since jobMain is a function, it returns a value. Without an explicit `return` statement you return `None`. You could just

```py
def jobmain(pth):
    # do stuff and assign flag
    return flag

# and inside tests
assert jobmain("") == 1
```

### 2) Use a class instead

If you want the jobMain to remember some state, then it is common practice to use objects. Then `flag` would be attribute of the object and could be accessed from outside, after you call any method (function) of `JobMain`. For example

```py
class JobMain:
    def __init__(self):
         self.flag = -1
    
    def run(self, pth):
        result = Myclass()
        if result.do_bite() is None:
            self.flag = 0
        if result.do_bite() is 1:
            self.flag = 1
        if result.do_bite() is 2:
            self.flag = 2

# and inside test
job = JobMain()
job.run()
assert job.flag == 1
```

### Note

I just copy-pasted your code for setting the flag. Note that you call `do_bite()` many times, if the resulting value is `None` or `1`. Also, when testing against a number, one should use `==` instead of `is`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to test 'flag' parameter inside JobMain?

You don't. It's an internal variable. Testing it would be [glass-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing); the test will break if the implementation changes.

Instead, test the effect of `flag`. This is [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). Only the interface is tested. If the implementation changes the test still works allowing the code to be aggressively [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

---

Note: If you don't hard code `result = Myclass()` you don't need to mock. Pass it in as an argument with the default being `Myclass()`.

```
def jobMain(directoryPath, result=Myclass()):
```

Then you don't need to patch `Myclass()`. Instead, pass in a mock object.

```
# I don't know unittest.mock very well, but something like this.

mock = Mock(Myclass)
mock.do_bite.return_value = 2
jobMain('', result=mock)
```

This also makes the code more flexible outside of testing.